# git - how do perform a diff for a specific file against a remote

Tags: git

Is there a way in git to do diffs on a specific file against a remote. I'm looking for an answer on all 3 states: unstaged, staged, and committed.

thanks!

Comment: git does have a man page you know ._.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git diff <remote-name> -- <filename>`

this should work for both staged and unstaged states.

For committed files,

`git diff <commit-sha1> <remote-name> -- <filename>`